# Odd error: 'FILE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'FILE'

Tags: c++, file, pointers, visual-c++-2008

I've seen people with a similar problem involving other file types, but nothing directly addressing FILE. As stated in the title, the error reads `'FILE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'FILE'`.

In my `main.h`, I included `<stdio.h>`, which, if I recall correctly, is the only standard library that has the FILE stream type in it. Then, in one header, I have `extern FILE *gvLog;`. I only included `<stdio.h>` in `main.h`, and I have used `#ifndef _MAINH_` to prevent it from being included twice, so why am I getting this error? What does it mean?

Comment: It probably means you're passing `*gvLog` instead of `gvLog` to a function with a `FILE*` argument. But you'd have to show us the code that's causing the error if you want more than a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'levels of indirection' language means that one is a type and the other is a pointer to that type.  In this case, `FILE` is a type and `FILE*` is a pointer to that type.  You are using one where the other was expected, most likely you are passing `*gvLog` (an object of type `FILE`) to a stdio function that expects a `FILE*` (a pointer to an object of type `FILE`).